# How to add more than one new property in an js object?

Tags: javascript

This question is based on the question:

[How to change a property of an object in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65708924/how-to-change-a-property-of-an-object-in-vue?noredirect=1#comment116187473_65708924)

```
render() {
   const hash = {};
   this.orders.forEach(o => {
      hash[o.supplier_name] = hash[o.supplier_name] + 1 || 1;
   })
   const suppliers = Object.keys(hash).map(name => ({ name: name, num: hash[name] }))
   console.log(suppliers);
}
```

Each order has n items. Each item has a quantity.

```
    [
        {
            "id": "54410f9d-b84a-4537-bc97-c312564f2a0d",
            "part_name": "1234",
            "part_number": "12345",
            "unit": "Stk.",
            "delivery_date": "13.01.2021",
            "supplier_id": "b3f2cced-1f61-48c2-9d30-ac7b09257a75",
            "supplier_name": "CNC AG",
            "supplier_stock": null,
            "confirmed": "2021-01-13T14:30:59.000000Z",
            "created_at": "13.01.2021",
            "confirmed_at": "13.01.2021 15:30",
            "confirmed_from": "John Doe",
            "time_to_confirm": 1.33,
            "delivery_time": null,
            "road_time": null,
            "items" : [
                {
                    "id": "54410f9d-b84a-4537-bc97-c3125ds4f2a0d",
                    "quantity": 5,
                },
                {
                    "id": "54410f9d-b84a-4537-bc97-cd12564f2a0d",
                    "quantity": 4,
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Finally, I like to have:

```
{ name: <supplier name>, num: <number of orders>, numItems: <total number of items>, quantity: <total quantity of quantity in items>, averageNumItems: <average of items per order> }
```

How can i get the final object?

Comment: can you share your orders array how it looks like

Comment: @ Alex I adde one order item. I extended the question to get also the average of items per order